# Trabajar con "named pipe" en python

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de escribir un sript python para leer de un fichero y enviar la salida a un named pipe o tuberia nombrada. A diferencia de la tuberia estandar, la named pipe persiste en el sistema y no en memoria.

Hasta el momento he visto que con popen se puede trabajar con tuberias estandar y tomar las entradas/salidas de sistemas pero no logro dar pie con bola con susodicha named pipe.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78) Actualiza tu pregunta con lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkfifo

Comment: Mi problema esta en leer y escribir en el pipe... No he logrado hacerlo noi con open ni popen

Answer (score 1):

Yo mismo me respondo... 
Named Pipe in Linux with a Python Example – roman10
http://www.roman10.net/2011/04/21/named-pipe-in-linux-with-a-python-example/

En esta url se explica como funciona la lectura y escritura usando un named pipe.

El detalle esta en que por cada escritura se debe abrir y cerrar el pipe.

py1.py

```
pipe = open('psquid', 'w') 
pipe.write('hola')
pipe.close()
```

py2.py

```
pipe2 = open('psquid', 'r')
pipe2.read()
'hola'
```

Saludos